# replaceWith() It works with even-ordered tags, but odd-ordered tags don't work..why?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to convert input tags into text
I found the following solution .. but unfortunately it works with the even-ordered input tags, either the odd input tags not work ..What is the reason for that

I mean JavaScript pure

I tried if with% to add 1+ to odd numbers ..but the problem is there

```js
let select = document.getElementsByClassName("replace");
for (let i = 0; i < select.length; i++)
{
        let data = select[i].value;
        select[i].replaceWith(data);
}
```

```html
<h1> Convert All input to text </h1>
<p>
  <input value='test 1' class='replace' />
  <input value='test 2' class='replace' />
  <input value='test 3' class='replace' />
  <input value='test 4' class='replace' />
  <input value='test 5' class='replace' />
  <input value='test 6' class='replace' />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

After replacing, the item is no longer in the elements list, because of the missing `class="replace"` and the length is shrinking.

You could check the length and replace at index zero until no more elements are available.

```js
let select = document.getElementsByClassName("replace");

while (select.length) {
    select[0].replaceWith(select[0].value);
}
```

```html
<h1> Convert All input to text </h1>
<p>
  <input value='test 1' class='replace' />
  <input value='test 2' class='replace' />
  <input value='test 3' class='replace' />
  <input value='test 4' class='replace' />
  <input value='test 5' class='replace' />
  <input value='test 6' class='replace' />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the differences between the returned value of querySelectorAll and getElementsByClassName is that the getElementsByClassName list is live, so changes you make to it are reflected right away (before the next loop iteration) whereas querySelectorAll is not live.  So one way to fix your problem is to switch getElementsByClassName for querySelectorAll.

```js
let select = document.querySelectorAll(".replace");
for (let i = 0; i < select.length; i++)
{
        let data = select[i].value;
        select[i].replaceWith(data);
}
```

```html
<h1> Convert All input to text </h1>
<p>
  <input value='test 1' class='replace' />
  <input value='test 2' class='replace' />
  <input value='test 3' class='replace' />
  <input value='test 4' class='replace' />
  <input value='test 5' class='replace' />
  <input value='test 6' class='replace' />
</p>
```